# in ShapeDrawable it sets color values of last JSON arrays

Tags: android, json, android-listview, baseadapter, android-shapedrawable

In my application I am using `listview` and I am also doing `json` parsing.,as per color code i am getting it and set it as ShapeDrawable with round,but the issue is i am getting values of last color code arrays in my every listitem,following is my json response and code can any one help me with that?

My Json Response

```
[
    {
        "id_product": "1445",
        "name": "Stylish Sleeveless Leather Vest",
        "price": 1990,
        "discount": 199,
        "colors": [
            "#000000",
            "#7E3517",
            "#C85A17"
        ],
        "sizes": [
            "Medium",
            "Large",
            "Small"
        ],
        "img_url": "",
        "popup_images": [

        ]
    },
    {
        "id_product": "1427",
        "name": "Stylish Slim Fit Designed PU Leather Jacket",
        "price": 3290,
        "discount": 329,
        "colors": [
            "#000000",
            "#C85A17"
        ],
        "sizes": [
            "Large",
            "Medium",
            "Small"
        ],
        "img_url": "",
        "popup_images": [

        ]
    }
]
```

now the issue is i am getting only two colors in my every listitems,and the colors are this two following

```
"colors": [
                "#000000",
                "#C85A17"
            ],
```

My Asynctask

```
class LoadAlbums extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        private JSONObject c;
        private String myColor;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
           // pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress));
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... args) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(INTEREST_ACCEPT_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonary = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    System.out.println("Test jsonObj"+jsonary);


                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonary.length(); i++) {
                        c = jsonary.getJSONObject(i);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_NAME, c.getString(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_NAME));
                        map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_PRICE,c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_PRICE));
                        map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_DISCOUNT, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_DISCOUNT));
                        map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_PRODUCTID, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_PRODUCTID));
                        map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_IMAGEURL, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_IMAGEURL));


                      // JSONArray colors=c.getJSONArray(INTEREST_ACCEPT_COLOR);
                       // JSONArray sizes=c.getJSONArray(INTEREST_ACCEPT_SIZES);

                        //user_img=c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_COLOR);

                        multimage=c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_IMAGEARRAY);

                        multimage = "";
                        userImgsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        JSONArray picsarray = c.getJSONArray(INTEREST_ACCEPT_IMAGEARRAY);
                        for(int a=0;a< picsarray.length();a++)
                        {
                            multimage = picsarray.getString(a);
                            userImgsArrayList.add(multimage);
                        }
                        Log.d("mylog", "userimagesarraylist  = " + userImgsArrayList);

                       user_img = "";
                        userImgArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        JSONArray picarray = c.getJSONArray(INTEREST_ACCEPT_COLOR);
                        map.put("colors", picarray.toString());
                        /*for(int a=0;a< picarray.length();a++)
                        {
                            user_img = picarray.getString(a);
                            userImgArrayList.add(user_img);
                        }*/
                       // Log.d("mylog", "curent color  = " + userImgArrayList);

                       /* if(userImgArrayList.size()==0) 
                        { 
                      //  Log.e("Size zero","No set color here"); 

                        } 
                        else if(userImgArrayList.size()==1) 
                        { 
                        first=userImgArrayList.get(0); 
                        second="#ffffff"; 
                        third="#ffffff"; 

                        } 
                        else if(userImgArrayList.size()==2) 
                        { 
                        first=userImgArrayList.get(0); 
                        second=userImgArrayList.get(1); 
                        third="#ffffff"; 

                        } 
                        else if(userImgArrayList.size()==3) 
                        { 
                        first=userImgArrayList.get(0); 
                        second=userImgArrayList.get(1); 
                        third=userImgArrayList.get(2); 

                        }
                        System.out.println("Color First"+first);
                       System.out.println("Color Second"+second);
                       System.out.println("Color Third"+third);
                       System.out.println("Color Fourth"+fourth);*/
                        data.add(map);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
            return data;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
                aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                aList.addAll(result);
                adapter = new CustomAdapterAccept(getActivity(),result);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });

        }

    }
```

My Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapterAccept extends BaseAdapter{

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listData;
        private AQuery aQuery;
        String rup="\u20B9";
        private static final String TAG_NAME="name";
       private static final String TAG_IMAGE="img_url";
        private static final String TAG_PRICE="price";

        public CustomAdapterAccept(Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> listData) {
            this.context = context;
            this.listData=listData;
            aQuery = new AQuery(this.context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return listData.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_listing_items, null);
               holder.propic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productlist_img);
                holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productlist_name);
                holder.txtprice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productlist_price);
                holder.firstcolor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstcolor);
                holder.secondcolor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondcolor);
                holder.thirdcolor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thirdcolor);
                holder.fourthcolor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fourthcolor);

                holder.cartview=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cartviews);
                holder.addtocart=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.productlist_addtocart);


               convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.txtproname.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
            holder.txtprice.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE));

            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(listData.get(position).get("colors"));
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int a=0;a< jsonArray.length();a++)
                {
                     try {
                        user_img = jsonArray.getString(a);
                        userImgArrayList.add(user_img);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

    if(userImgArrayList.size()==0) 
                        { 
                      //  Log.e("Size zero","No set color here"); 

                        } 
                        else if(userImgArrayList.size()==1) 
                        { 
                        first=userImgArrayList.get(0); 
                        second="#ffffff"; 
                        third="#ffffff"; 

                        } 
                        else if(userImgArrayList.size()==2) 
                        { 
                        first=userImgArrayList.get(0); 
                        second=userImgArrayList.get(1); 
                        third="#ffffff"; 

                        } 
                        else if(userImgArrayList.size()==3) 
                        { 
                        first=userImgArrayList.get(0); 
                        second=userImgArrayList.get(1); 
                        third=userImgArrayList.get(2); 

                        }
                        System.out.println("Color First"+first);
                       System.out.println("Color Second"+second);
                       System.out.println("Color Third"+third);
                       System.out.println("Color Fourth"+fourth);

            ShapeDrawable biggerCircle= new ShapeDrawable( new OvalShape());
            biggerCircle.setIntrinsicHeight( 60 );
            biggerCircle.setIntrinsicWidth( 60);
            biggerCircle.setBounds(new Rect(30, 30, 30, 30));
            biggerCircle.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(first));
            holder.firstcolor.setBackgroundDrawable(biggerCircle); 

            ShapeDrawable biggerCirclesec= new ShapeDrawable( new OvalShape());
            biggerCirclesec.setIntrinsicHeight( 60 );
            biggerCirclesec.setIntrinsicWidth( 60);
            biggerCirclesec.setBounds(new Rect(30, 30, 30, 30));
            biggerCirclesec.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(second));
            holder.secondcolor.setBackgroundDrawable(biggerCirclesec); 

            ShapeDrawable biggerCirclethree= new ShapeDrawable( new OvalShape());
            biggerCirclethree.setIntrinsicHeight( 60 );
            biggerCirclethree.setIntrinsicWidth( 60);
            biggerCirclethree.setBounds(new Rect(30, 30, 30, 30));
            biggerCirclethree.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(third));
            holder.thirdcolor.setBackgroundDrawable(biggerCirclethree); 


            aQuery.id(holder.propic).image(listData.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE),true,true,0,R.drawable.meracaslogo);

            holder.cartview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AddtoCart tf = new AddtoCart();
                     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                 //   bundle.putString("Brandnunamm", aList.get(position).get((USER_NAME)));
                    tf.setArguments(bundle);
                      FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                      FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                      ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
                      ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                      ft.addToBackStack(null);
                      ft.commit();
                }
            });
            holder.addtocart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    new AttemptLogin().execute();
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            holder.propic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(userImgsArrayList != null && userImgsArrayList.size() > 0) { 
                        Fullimages tf = new Fullimages();
                         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                         bundle.putStringArrayList("user_images", userImgsArrayList);
                      //  bundle.putString("Brandnunamm", aList.get(position).get((USER_NAME)));
                         tf.setArguments(bundle);
                          FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                          FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                          ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
                          ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                          ft.addToBackStack(null);
                          ft.commit();
                        }
                    else
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Images Availabel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
            // image parameter : 1 : memory cache,2:file cache,3:target width,4:fallback image
            return convertView;
        }
        class ViewHolder{
            public TextView fourthcolor;
            public TextView thirdcolor;
            public TextView secondcolor;
            public ImageView cartview;
            TextView txtprice;
            ImageView propic;
            TextView txtproname;
            TextView firstcolor;
            Button addtocart;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i am getting values of last color code arrays in my every listitem

Because `userImgsArrayList` every time created inside for loop which is used to iterate `jsonary` JSONArray.

Instead of string color in `ArrayList` just store it in `Map` which is used for storing other details:

```
JSONArray picColors = c.getJSONArray(INTEREST_ACCEPT_COLOR);
map.put("colors", picColors.toString());
```

and now move all color logic inside `getView` method:

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(listData.get(position).get("colors"));
for(int a=0;a< picarray.length();a++)
    {
         user_img = picarray.getString(a);
         userImgArrayList.add(user_img);
    }
 ////....
```

Comment: but in every color array the values and size is different

Comment: @Jolly: See my edit answer. let me know if still facing any issue

Comment: @Jolly: yes right but also need to move code from `Log.d("mylog", "curent color  = " + userImgArrayList);` line to `System.out.println("Color First"+first);` from `doInBackground ` in `getView ` to update color accoding to List row

Comment: it gives error nullpointer here          biggerCircle.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(first));

Comment: do i need to remove that same else if ladder from doinbackground??

Comment: @Jolly: yes remove from `doinbackground `

Comment: see this for response http://pastie.org/10639237 and in my logcat i get http://pastie.org/10639235

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98309/discussion-between-jolly-and--k).

Comment: it is showing color values of first arrays..check pasties